# How would I go about passing a variable from an .on() event to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to insert buttons dynamically into a document, and I want to have the buttons clickable and grab the value of each button and export them in the conosle.log. Right now I have the button clickable, but I can't figure out how to pass the button value from the .on() to the function, any advice?

html

```
<button id="testTagButton" class="yt-chip" title="test button please ignore"><span>test button please ignore</span></button>
```

javascript

```
$(document).on('click','#testTagButton',tagInsert);


function tagInsert(){
    console.log("Button Value should go here");
}
```

I have to use .on() afaik because I'm using append to insert the button into the document

Comment: what do you mean by button value, the text of the span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply refer to the context (aka this):

```
function tagInsert(){
  console.log(
    this.id, //a regular DOM prop
    this.title, 
    $(this).text() //or utilizing jquery again
    //or whatever
   );
}
```

Comment: Perfect, you're the man. I knew it would be something simple, thank you!

it hasn't been 10 minutes since I posted, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer when the cooldown is up.

Comment: @gambsmoore glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which value you were looking for, but $(this).id or $(this).text would do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data-` and the `$.data()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data("test"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-test="123" id="test">
Test
</button>
```